# Formula field to check if the status of account is changed today

Tags: process-builder, formula-field, checkbox

I have a requirement where a check box on account should be true when the status__c field of account is changed today.

Comment: While I see you've received a solution, I want to emphasize that we expect posts to contain a *question* based on the knowledge, research, and work you've done so far. We discourage posts that simply ask for the solution to a requirement. Please read [ask] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to be solve without code using the follow approach.

1. Create a Process Builder (Account Object) that update a Date field when the status changes
2. Create a checkbox formula field comparing this Date field with Today()

Comment: thanks for the solution Peixoto.... :)